# Why does querying based on the first clustering key require an ALLOW FILTERING?

Tags: cassandra

Say I have this Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  customerId int, 
  datetime date, 
  amount int, 
  PRIMARY KEY (customerId, datetime)
);
```

Then why would the following query require an ALLOW FILTERING:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date >= '2020-01-01'
```

Cassandra could just go to all the individual partitions (i.e. customers) and filter on the clustering key `date`. Since `date` is sorted there is no need to retrieve all the rows in `orders` and filter out the ones that match my where clause (as far as I understand it).

I hope someone can enlighten me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This happens because for normal work, Cassandra needs the partition key - it's used to find what machine(s) are storing the data for it. If you don't have partition key, like, in your example, Cassandra need to scan all data to find those that are matching your query. And this requires the use of the `ALLOW FILTERING`.

P.S. Data is sorted only inside the individual partitions, not globally.

Comment: Thanks Alex. But my point is that Cassandra can scan all partitions, but within those partitions it can still do quick filtering due to the sorted data structure. Hence, it doesn't need to fetch *all* the data.

Comment: Haha OK, can you explain why? Can't it just do this in two steps: 1) list all n partition keys 2) run n queries like `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customerid='{key}' date >= '2020-01-01'`? Then you don't have to go through all data, right?

Comment: In Cassandra data for the same partition could be split between multiple files, with data received via repair, hints, with different timestamps, etc. As result, You have multiple files on disk that you need to read to construct full version of the partition, and find the data that is related to your query...

Comment: I'm still not following. As far as I understood it, if you filter based on partition key (and cluster key) your query is (relatively) fast. Otherwise it's (relatively) slow, because it first needs to fetch all the data (within that partition). Now in my example I **do** filter only on partition key and cluster key. All I'm asking from Cassandra is to keep track of all the partition keys and run _n_ queries for each of the _n_ partition keys.

Comment: Cassandra has other means of doing that - you can do it if necessary, but you need to understand trade offs... For beginning, just try answer the question - what will be performance in case if you have 1 billion of partition keys? It’s not a rare situation...

Comment: For full scan you need to use Spark, DSBulk or something like that, that is optimized for such operations. Or in the worst case, when you can’t use these tools, something like this: https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java

Comment: Cassandra is heavily optimized for OTLP workloads that operate on one partition a time

Comment: Righttt. Yeah that makes sense. So we're working with O(100.000) partitions, which makes it a different story I guess. So what you're saying, is that it's much quicker for cassandra to fetch all data and post-process it, instead of running those _n_ queries (if _n_ is really large)?

Comment: To handle this situation, there is a thing called range scan, that is doing filtering on the Cassandra side, and it can read only data that is matching the filter - but this is not done automatically, it should be done explicitly, like it's done in Spark, DSBulk, or the Java code that I linked